# Find a substring length $k$ with maximum occurrences

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, big-o-notation, hash-tables

Given a string length $S$, find a substring length $k$ that has the most occurrences in the given string.

We want $O(S)$ time complexity in an average case.

I think the solution lies in sophisticated use of *Rabin-Karp algorithm*.

I've tried to use the sliding window method, but that results in $O(S * k)$ time complexity, because when inserting into the hash table we have to actually compare the substrings in $O(k)$ time.

So how can I improve it to the desired time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Each substring occurrence of your length $k$ pattern is the suffix of a of a substring. As such, a *suffix tree* will provide a fast way to store all possible suffixes and - in particular in your case - all substrings of length $k$, as well as provide a way to detect when you are reading a $k$-substring that has been seen before.

In your particular case of only caring about length $k$-substrings, you can improve the suffix tree to only keep nodes up to depth $k$ as you don't need to go beyond that.

Suffix trees give $\Theta(n)$ runtimes for a lot of String-processing problems. See a list of such problems on the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree